# Запрет на просмотр страниц сайта PHP

Tags: php

### Я хочу сделать запрет на просмотр страниц сайта.

*Например:*
Если пользователь зашёл на страницу `signup.php`, создал новый профиль и потом снова заходит на эту страницу, то заблокировать ему доступ на просмотр.

---

Не знаю, нужно ли это делать вообще, но в рамках безопасности думаю будет самое то!

---

И я делаю так:
создаю переменную в массиве `$_SESSION[]`, например `$_SESSION['logged-in]`и присваиваю ей значение `Правда true`. И потом делаю проверку. Если пользователь залогинился (`$_SESSION['logged-in'] == true`), то просто прекратить выполнение кода `exit`.

```
<?php session_start();

    if ($_SESSION['logged-in']) {
        echo '403';
        exit;
    }
```

**В общем, вопрос: Как правильно сделать подобную защиту и есть ли такое вообще на популярных сайтах?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Такие проверки действительно существуют и они нужны.

Вместо того чтобы создавать отдельно запись в сессии лучше проверять на наличие куки в которой вы храните идентификатор пользователя (я же думаю вы используете куки, если нет, тогда проверяете на сессию в которой храните идентификатор).

К примеру можете сделать такую функцию и её подставлять на страницы где вам это нужно:

```
function is_auth() {

    return isset($_COOKIE['email']); //или что вы там пишите при авторизации пользователя
}
```

И потом в вашем коде вызываете эту функцию и запрещаете выполнение скрипта или разрешаете.

Если же действительно используете только сессии делайте проверку на наличие сессии.

Comment: Да, сейчас только сессии.. Ну я был на верном пути?)

Comment: @Cactus да, ваш вариант тоже имеет право на жизнь)